# After using pyinstaller for packaging, an error of ImportError: The _imagingft C module is not installed is reported

Tags: python-3.7

After using pyinstaller for packaging, an error of ImportError: The _imagingft C module is not installed is reported

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
  File "Face_Login_UI.py", line 236, in Face_detection
  File "Face_Login_UI.py", line 140, in draw_warring
  File "PIL\ImageFont.py", line 959, in truetype
  File "PIL\ImageFont.py", line 956, in freetype
  File "PIL\ImageFont.py", line 219, in __init__
  File "PIL\ImageFont.py", line 58, in __getattr__
ImportError: The _imagingft C module is not installed`
```

```
pip uninstall pillow
pip install pillow
```

No effect

Comment: python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow